# how to map enum values to type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an enum type which looks this:

```
export enum API_TYPE {
  INDEX = "index_api",
  CREATE = "create_api",
  SHOW = "show_api",
  UPDATE = "update_api",
  DELETE = "destroy_api"
};
```

now, I have a function which takes a number and api_type parameter

```
export function abc (id: number, api_type:?) =>
```

for this function, possible values for api_type would be values of keys of enum `api_type`

What is the best way to discuss type of `api_type` parameter of `function abc`?

One way would be to `export type Api_Type = "index_api" | "create_api" | "show_api" | "update_api" | "destroy_api"`

and then

```
export function abc (id: number, api_type:Api_Type) =>
```

but this way if I add new property (key) to  `enum API_TYPE {` i would also have to remember to manually add it to `Api_Type`

Is there a way, I can map enum value to a type? or a better way to do this?

Comment: The normal way to do this would be `function abc(id: number, api_type: API_TYPE)` and you would call it like `abc(123, API_TYPE.INDEX)` and not `abc(123, "index_api")`.  If that doesn't work for you, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

```js
enum ApiType {
  INDEX = "index_api",
  CREATE = "create_api",
  SHOW = "show_api",
  UPDATE = "update_api",
  DELETE = "destroy_api"
};

 function abc (id: number, api_type:ApiType) {
    console.log(api_type);
 }
```

Here is a [Demo Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggDgSwCoE87CgbwFBSgSQDkARAUQA0oBeKAIgRABNgAPAfQENFaAaXKAMIAlUjCSlqdAMYAnYBwAuwTtz54AygAkA8gHVJtAM4ALAPYB3FQl78AqgAViYiTVpg4jRcq7W1UMgAypOIGzIYKMqYoVrTYAL4A3Ni4AGZgIFIKCKYgUBwARlJQABQIjABcUOAQ+cAyPHmIbApowOXwyK0AlFj8eFI5hqYANsAAdMOmAObFPs3dSVBxuAVSxQCMDR2o6GPCouJdCUA)